# Prove that $2 \int_{x}^{x+1} \log(t) dt \geq \log(x (x+1))$.

Tags: calculus, geometry, inequality, logarithms

Prove that $2 \int_{x}^{x+1} \log(t) \,dt \geq \log(x (x+1))$.

I want proof of this without using geometry. I need to know the techniques to solve this other than geometry.

One can easily see this inequality is true for $x>0$ just by drawing $\log(t)$ (real) graph and observing the area of the trapezium which joins $x, x+1, \log(x+1)$ and $\log(x)$ is less than area under the curve between $x$ and $x+1$.

Comment: You can make the geometric argument more analytic, it is just saying that the log function is concave. Write concavity inequality between $x$ and $x+1$ then integrate.

Comment: Hint: By weighted AM-GM inequality, $(x+t)^1\ge x^{1-t}(x+1)^t$.

Comment: Hints: [1] What is the $~\displaystyle \frac{d ~\left\{ ~t \left[ \log(t) - 1 ~\right] ~\right\} }{dt} ~? ~$ [2] If you can reduce the problem to showing that $~h(x) = f(x) - g(x) \geq 0,~$ for all $~x > 0,~$ then the next step would be to analyze the behavior of $~h(x),~$ by (perhaps) examining $~h'(x), ~h''(x), ~$ and $~h(1).$

Comment: By the way, this inequality is false between $0<x<1$. Because logt is negative in this range. But right hand side of inequality is always positive.

Comment: By Jensen's inequality, and the concavity of the logarithmic
function on $[x,x+1],$ there is also an upper bound:
$$
2\int_x^{x+1}\log(t)\,dt\leqslant2\log\left(\int_x^{x+1}t\,dt\right)
=2\log(x+\tfrac12)=\log[x(x+1)+\tfrac14].
$$
A few numerical values, calculated using the exact value of the
integral $\int_x^{x+1}\log(t)\,dt=(x+1)\log(x+1)-x\log(x)-1$:
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
x&\log[x(x+1)]&2\int_x^{x+1}\log(t)\,dt&\log[x(x+1)+\tfrac14]\\
1&0.6931&0.7726&0.8109\\
2&1.7918&1.8191&1.8326\\
3&2.4849&2.4987&2.5055\\
4&2.9957&3.0040&3.0082\\
5&3.4012&3.4067&3.4095
\end{array}
$$

Comment: The table in my previous comment suggests the inequality:
$$
(6x+5)\log(x+1)>(6x+1)\log(x)+4\log(x+\tfrac12)+6\qquad(x\geqslant
1).
$$
But Python suggests that this is false for values of $x$ greater
than about $1000.$ It just seemed as if the value of
the integral expression was slightly more than two thirds of the way
between the lower and upper bounds $\ldots$ I don't know if it's just
a numerical artefact, but the graph of the difference between those
two functions plotted by Wolfram Alpha seems to oscillate weirdly
between very small values, even for pretty large values of $x.$

Comment: @MetehanTuran Could you please check. The Inequality is true for $x>0$

Comment: @MANJUNATHAMR yes it is. :) I will delete my comment.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley It is very interesting. After your comments I found similar things while working with upper bounds in terms $\log(x(x+1))$.

Comment: The Wolfram Alpha plot of the rearranged expression
$$
f(x) = (6x+1)\log\left(1 + \frac1x\right) +
4\log\left(1+\frac1{2x+1}\right) - 6 \qquad (x>0)
$$
looks saner, but is still puzzling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the variable of integration in two different ways:
\begin{multline*}
2\int_x^{x+1}\log(t)\,dt = \int_0^1\log(x+u)\,du + \int_0^1\log(x+1-u)\,du \\
= \int_0^1[\log(x+u) + \log(x+1-u)]\,du = \int_0^1\log[(x+u)(x+1-u)]\,du \\
= \int_0^1\log[x(x+1)+u(1-u)]\,du \geqslant \int_0^1\log[x(x+1)]\,du
= \log[x(x+1)].
\end{multline*}

Comment: You made the solution exceptionally clear. I'm curious about the thought process behind identifying such a clever trick or pattern. How did you come across it?

Comment: It was based on a mistake, but I got lucky! I thought, and still think, that the most natural method of proof is the one you gave in the question, as elaborated in @Héhéhé's comment. Trying to think how to express it without too much calculation, I imagined the integral as a summation, and thought to pair low values with high values, i.e., $x+u$ with $x+1-u,$ for $u\in[0,1].$ I imagined this would still be an expression of concavity, but in fact the resulting inequality went in the opposite direction. Fortunately, the calculation was simple, and it worked itself out essentially automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Although an answer has been accepted, I am writing this answer as the given problem could be deduced as a special case of some general one. This arose from the observation that the given inequality looks like:
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(t)\, dt \geq (b-a) \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}.$$

Suppose, we ask the question under what conditions on $f$, the above inequality holds good, it turns out that

> $\textbf{Statement:}$ if $f(x)$ is twice differentiable and concave  on $[a,b]$, then
> $$ \int\limits_{a}^{b} f(t)\, dt \geq (b-a) \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}.$$

To see why this is so, consider the function $H(x)$ defined by
$$H(x) = \int\limits_{a}^x f(t)\, dt - (x-a) \frac{f(x)+f(a)}{2}.$$

Clearly

$$H^{(2)}(x) = -(x-a)f^{(2)}(x)/2 \geq 0, \,\, \forall \,x\in[a,b].$$

Moreover, $H(a)=0 =H^{\prime}(a)$. Thus it can never happen that for any $x\in [a,b]$, $H(x) < 0$ (Why?). Hence
$$H(x) \geq 0, \,\, \forall\, x\in[a,b].$$

$\textbf{Edit:}$

As mentioned in the comment, only concavity was enough. This is just an elaboration of the comment of Héhéhé.

If $f$ were concave on $[a,b]$, then for every $t\in [0,1]$, we would have had
$$f(a(1-t)+bt) \geq (1-t) f(a) + tf(b).$$

Simply integrating the above with respect to $t$ from 0 to 1 along with  the substitution:

$$a(1-t)+bt = \theta,$$
on LHS, we would have arrived at

$$\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(\theta) \, d\theta \geq (b-a) \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}.$$

Comment: I think @Héhéhé's comment gives a similarly general result, without the need to assume that $f$ is twice differentiable. (Perhaps someone [cough] should turn the comment into nan answer.)

Comment: Agreed: As $\int\limits_{0}^{1} f((1-t)x+t(x+1)) \,dt \geq \frac{f(x+1)+f(x)}{2}$ starting with the inequality $f((1-t)x+t(x+1))\geq (1-t) f(x)+tf(x+1)$.

Comment: Edited to include the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=2 \int_{x}^{x+1} \ln(t) \,dt - \ln(x (x+1))$

hence $f'(x)=2 \ln(1+\frac{1}{x})-\frac{(2x+1)}{x(x+1)}$

$$f''(x)=\frac{-2}{x^2+x}+(\frac{2x^2+2x+1}{x^2(x+1)^2})=\frac{1}{x^2(x+1)^2}$$

Now $$f''(x)>0$$

Which means $f'(x)$ is increasing function

Now $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty}f'(x)=0$

Which means $f'(x)<0$

It follows $f(x)$ is an decreasing function

Now $f(x)=\ln( \frac{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{2x+1})}{e^2})$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=\ln 1=0$, Which means $f(x)>0$

Which suggests $f(x)=2 \int_{x}^{x+1} \ln(t) \,dt - \ln(x (x+1))>0$

It follows

$2 \int_{x}^{x+1} \ln(t) \,dt>\ln(x (x+1))$

Comment: I have a doubt here. The function $f(x)$ is not defined for negetive numbers. Why you let $x$ to $-\infty$ ?

Comment: @MANJUNATHAMR, fair point, Edited to clarify

Comment: Very beautifully done. You just mention what I thought of adding with the problem. That is $\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=\ln 1=0$. Which shows for larger $x$ LHS and RHS of the inequality are asymptotic to each other. Area of the trapezium I mentioned and area under the curve becomes same as we move along the curve in positive direction. My intuition says not just the area of the trapezium but also area of the rectangle $x(x+1)$ becomes equal for area under the curve $\log(t)$ between $x$ and $x+1$ for larger x. Isn't it?

Comment: @MANJUNATHAMR, If you mean the rectangle which has x-axis(length)=$(x+1)-x=1$ and breadth=$\ln(x+1)$, Then difference between area of trapezium and area of rectangle is given by D=$\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$, When $x \to \infty$, $D \to 0$, Which means the area under curve squeezes between Area of rectangle and area of trapezium